# How to create an interceptor for annotation @Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, aspectj, interceptor, spring2.x

I joined an existing project who use 2 mechanisms for the front-end with spring mvc:

- A) controllers classes extends
  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController
- B) controllers classes uses annotation @Controller.

Now I found an interceptor:

```
@Aspect
public class RequestMonitor {

    @Autowired
    private RequestMonitorService requestMonitorService;

    @Before("execution(* org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller+.handleRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse))"
            + "&& args(request,response)")
    public void storeUserAccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        requestMonitorService.storeUserAccess(request);
    }
}
```

who catch all requests from org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller (mechanism A)

How can I adapt to intercept all other controllers with annotations "@Controller": org.springframework.stereotype.Controller (mechanism B)

Answer (score 3):

You have the [HandlerInterceptorAdapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html) class. You can extend it and make use of the methods in your subclass :

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception

public void postHandle(
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
        Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView)
        throws Exception
```

And you need to register your interceptor i.e:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="my.fully.qualified.package.RequestInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: We use Spring 2.5 and not 3 :(